# Is there a number "value equals"?

Tags: java, numbers, equals, primitive

By default, Java does [Binary Numeric Promotion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2) for primitives, but does not do the same thing for objects. Here's a quick test to demonstrate:

```
public static void main(String... args) {
  if(100 == 100L) System.out.println("first trial happened");
  if(Integer.valueOf(100).equals(Long.valueOf(100))) {
    System.out.println("second trial was true");
  } else {
    System.out.println("second trial was false");
  }
  if(100D == 100L) System.out.println("third trial, fun with doubles");
}
```

Output:

```
first trial happened
second trial was false
third trial, fun with doubles
```

This is *obviously* correct behavior - an `Integer` is **not** a `Long`. However, does there exist a "value equals" for `Number` subclasses that would return true the same way that `100 == 100L` returns true? Or `100d == 100L`? In other words, is there a method (that is not `Object.equals`) that will do the equivalent of the Binary Numeric Promotion behavior for objects?

Comment: What about `10*(0.1+0.2) == 3`? In my experience it's generally uncommon to need to compare floating-point and integer numbers.

Comment: @MattBall Obviously doubles make it more complicated with rounding errors. You can handle that case with `org.hamcrest.number.IsCloseTo.closeTo()`, or just check if the difference is less than some error.

Comment: Looking at the [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html) page, it looks like `Number` itself is pretty barebones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/PrimitivesExplained#General_utility_methods) provides several nice utilities for working with primitives, including a compare() method for each type:

```
int compare(prim a, prim b)
```

And in fact, this same functionality has been added to the JDK as of Java 7.  These methods don't provide arbitrary `Number` comparisons, however they give you the granularity to define any type-safe comparison you'd like, by choosing which class (`Longs`, `Doubles`, etc.) to use.

```
@Test
public void valueEquals() {
  // Your examples:
  assertTrue(100 == 100l);
  assertTrue(100d == 100l);
  assertNotEquals(100, 100l); // assertEquals autoboxes primitives
  assertNotEquals(new Integer(100), new Long(100));

  // Guava
  assertTrue(Longs.compare(100, 100l) == 0);
  assertTrue(Longs.compare(new Integer(100), new Long(100)) == 0);
  assertTrue(Doubles.compare(100d, 100l) == 0);
  // Illegal, expected compare(int, int)
  //Ints.compare(10, 10l);

  // JDK
  assertTrue(Long.compare(100, 100l) == 0);
  assertTrue(Long.compare(new Integer(100), new Long(100)) == 0);
  assertTrue(Double.compare(100d, 100l) == 0);
  // Illegal, expected compare(int, int)
  //Integer.compare(10, 10l);
  // Illegal, expected compareTo(Long) which cannot be autoboxed from int
  //new Long(100).compareTo(100);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This

```
if(100 == 100L) System.out.println("first trial happened");
```

you get some [Binary Numeric Promotion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2)

> Otherwise, if either operand is of type long, the other is converted
>   to long.

Therefore `100L == 100L`

This

```
if(Integer.valueOf(100).equals(Long.valueOf(100))) {
    System.out.println("second trial was true");
} else {
    System.out.println("second trial was false");
}
```

"fails", because the `Integer#equals()` method checks if the passed object is `instanceof` `Integer`. Returns `false` right away if it isn't.

This

```
if(100d == 100l) System.out.println("third trial, fun with doubles");
```

Same as first, but `double` instead of `long`.

All the `equals()` methods of the boxed types check `instanceof` for their respective types, so there's no way to make them work.

You might not like the solution, but it will be something similar

```
if (Integer.valueOf(100).intValue() == Long.valueOf(100).longValue()) {
    System.out.println("second trial was true");
} else {
    System.out.println("second trial was false");
}
```

Comment: I know **why** it happens, I'm more interested in "does there exist a value equals method" because "object equals" is obviously not what is needed here.

Comment: The only way is to cast them to their respective types and use one of the `xxxValue()` methods to convert them.

Comment: @Vash I agree, I am looking for SOME OTHER method

Comment: @durron597, The valid method for number is usage of compareTo interface

Comment: @vash Except `compareTo` accepts an argument of the same type as the calling object, so OP don't forget to convert to that type.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Another way to put it is, is there some method that does Binary Numeric Promotion when comparing objects?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, The case you write about will be detected on compile level so there is no way to mist it ;-). But nice from your side that you have pointed that out.

Comment: @durron597 You will have to use one of the `xxxValue()` methods and let the primitive types do their thing. There is no general way to do it that I am aware of.

Comment: @durron597, Not natively implemented as far I know. You pass this by writing own comparator that will use `Number` interface as arguments  and `BigDecimal` to perform the compare operation. `BinaryNumericPromotionComparator.compareTo(100,100L) == 0` could result with true.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `compareTo` method instead of `equals` when you care only about the number value.

Comment: `compareTo` expects an object of the same type as an argument, meaning it can't cast an `int` to a `Long`; `new Long(100).compareTo(100)` won't compile, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

I personnaly came to this solution using Apache commons:

```
public class NumEqualUtils {
    static boolean areEqualsNumerical(Serializable... values) {
      return areNumerical(values) && 
        Stream.of(values)
          .map(s -> NumberUtils.createBigDecimal(s.toString()).doubleValue() )
          .distinct()
          .count() == 1;
    }

    static boolean areNumerical(Serializable... values) {
      if(values == null || values.length == 0)
        return false;
      return Arrays.stream(values).allMatch( s -> s != null && NumberUtils.isCreatable(s.toString()) );
    }
}
```

```
@Test
void test_areEqualsNumerical() {
    assertTrue( NumEqualUtils.areEqualsNumerical("123", 123d) );

    assertTrue( NumEqualUtils.areEqualsNumerical("123", 123) );
    assertTrue( NumEqualUtils.areEqualsNumerical("123", 123f) );
    assertTrue( NumEqualUtils.areEqualsNumerical("123", 123l) );
    
    assertTrue( NumEqualUtils.areEqualsNumerical("123", Integer.valueOf(123)) );
    assertTrue( NumEqualUtils.areEqualsNumerical("123", Double.valueOf(123d)) );
    assertTrue( NumEqualUtils.areEqualsNumerical("123", Float.valueOf(123f)) );
    assertTrue( NumEqualUtils.areEqualsNumerical("123", Long.valueOf(123l)) );
    assertTrue( NumEqualUtils.areEqualsNumerical("123", BigDecimal.valueOf(123d)) );
    
    assertTrue( NumEqualUtils.areEqualsNumerical("123", 
        Integer.valueOf(123), "123", Double.valueOf(123d), Float.valueOf(123f), Long.valueOf(123l),"123", BigDecimal.valueOf(123d)) );
    
    assertFalse( NumEqualUtils.areEqualsNumerical("123", 
        Integer.valueOf(123), "124" /*<== different*/, Double.valueOf(123d), Float.valueOf(123f), Long.valueOf(123l),"123", BigDecimal.valueOf(123d)) );

}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Test
void test_areNumerical() {
    assertFalse( NumEqualUtils.areNumerical((Serializable) null));
    assertFalse( NumEqualUtils.areNumerical((Object[]) new Serializable[] {}) );
    assertFalse( NumEqualUtils.areNumerical("123", new Serializable() {}) );
    assertFalse( NumEqualUtils.areNumerical("123", "not a number") );
    assertFalse( NumEqualUtils.areNumerical("123", "456,89") ); // . is separator

    assertTrue( NumEqualUtils.areNumerical("123", 456) );
    assertTrue( NumEqualUtils.areNumerical("123", 785D) );
    assertTrue( NumEqualUtils.areNumerical("123", 785f, 758L, 654, Integer.valueOf(54), Long.valueOf(96l), Double.valueOf(95.4564d)) );
    
}
```

It works fine for my purpose although I did not tested it extensively to see how it behaves with all Number subtypes. I especially not tested extensive double precision because that was of no use for my purpose.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).