# Comparing "T extends Number" for equality

Tags: java, generics

I have a matrix class which takes in a generic object which extends Number.

For example:

```
public class Matrix<T extends Number>
```

I am trying to compare two matrices which have the same values:

```
Matrix:
row=[0] 273 455 
row=[1] 243 235 
row=[2] 244 205 
row=[3] 102 160
```

and

```
Matrix:
row=[0] 273 455 
row=[1] 243 235 
row=[2] 244 205 
row=[3] 102 160
```

In the Matrix class, I have a equals method which looks like this:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (!(obj instanceof Matrix))
        return false;

    Matrix<T> m = (Matrix<T>) obj;
    if (this.rows != m.rows)
        return false;
    if (this.cols != m.cols)
        return false;
    for (int i=0; i<matrix.length; i++) {
        T t1 = matrix[i];
        T t2 = m.matrix[i];
        if (!t1.equals(t2))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

This line is failing:

```
t1.equals(t2)
```

even when the two numbers are equal. e.g. "273" and "273"

When I debug the equals method, it is failing because it is assuming the numbers are Longs:

This is from Java SDK Long.class:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
if (obj instanceof Long) {
    return value == ((Long)obj).longValue();
}
return false;
}
```

Essentially, it fails because the obj isn't an instance of Long.

I can easily change my equals method to do:

```
        if (t1.longValue()!=t2.longValue())
            return false;
```

But I am wonder what is the correct way to check for equality in this situation and why the equals method on the generic T is assuming it's a Long.

EDIT:

My testing code is defining ''Matrix generic type of Integer'' which makes the equality testing (which is comparing using Long) strange to me.

Testing code:

```
    Matrix<Integer> matrix1 = new Matrix<Integer>(4, 3);
    matrix1.set(0, 0, 14);
    matrix1.set(0, 1, 9);
    matrix1.set(0, 2, 3);
    matrix1.set(1, 0, 2);
    matrix1.set(1, 1, 11);
    matrix1.set(1, 2, 15);
    matrix1.set(2, 0, 0);
    matrix1.set(2, 1, 12);
    matrix1.set(2, 2, 17);
    matrix1.set(3, 0, 5);
    matrix1.set(3, 1, 2);
    matrix1.set(3, 2, 3);

    Matrix<Integer> matrix2 = new Matrix<Integer>(3, 2);
    matrix2.set(0, 0, 12);
    matrix2.set(0, 1, 25);
    matrix2.set(1, 0, 9);
    matrix2.set(1, 1, 10);
    matrix2.set(2, 0, 8);
    matrix2.set(2, 1, 5);

    Matrix<Integer> result1 = new Matrix<Integer>(4,2);
    result1.set(0, 0, 273);
    result1.set(0, 1, 455);
    result1.set(1, 0, 243);
    result1.set(1, 1, 235);
    result1.set(2, 0, 244);
    result1.set(2, 1, 205);
    result1.set(3, 0, 102);
    result1.set(3, 1, 160);

    Matrix<Integer> matrix3 = matrix1.multiply(matrix2);
    if (!matrix3.equals(result1)) {
        System.err.println("Matrix multiplication error. matrix3="+matrix3+" result1"+result1);
        return false;
    }
```

[Here](https://code.google.com/p/java-algorithms-implementation/source/browse/src/com/jwetherell/algorithms/data_structures/Matrix.java) is the link to the Matrix code without the equals() method defined. I haven't checked in the equals() code yet.

Comment: what if in the if statement, you do a class comparison ``if(!t1.getClass().equals(t2.getClass()) && !t1.equals(t2)) { ... }``

Comment: What other type is it? and why can there be multiple types? Using ``Number`` means that your values can be a of variety of types, such as BigDecimal, BigInteger, Byte, Double, Float, Integer, Long, Short,...

Comment: It seems like a flaw that the API requires `Long.equals` to be equal only to another `Long`, and there isn't an equality function that can compare it to any `Number` (or at least the known `Number` classes provided by the JDK).  Unfortunately, I didn't see any such equality function in Apache Commons either.

Comment: You have not shown the declarations of the two `Matrix<T>` objects that are being compared.  Are they both `Matrix<Long>`? If they were the comparison should work.  I strongly suspect you have two `Matrix<T>` objects with different types for `T`.  If that is the case then the comparison WILL fail because it will use `Object#equals()` for comparison.  The key here is that `Number` has no `equals()` method of its own because it cannot know how to coerce two arbitrary numbers into a form that supports comparison.

Comment: @JimGarrison I've added the testing code.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19410357/is-there-a-number-value-equals

Comment: With respect to the question of why it's comparing using `Long` when all you have are `Matrix<Integer>`: I think we would need to see how the `matrix` member is declared, how it's assigned in your constructor, and possibly the body of `set`.  Something in your code may be causing the compiler to create a `Long` to be stored in `matrix[i]` for some `i`.

Comment: @ajb I have linked to the Matrix code.

Comment: @Justin Thanks for the link.  I've looked over it--see my answer.

Comment: Yikes - might I suggest a `Matrix` constructor that accepts a 2D array for easier initialization of those test matrices?

Comment: @ajb Thanks, great answer. Thanks for explaining the why "Long" equal is used. I am still evaluating a good solution to the equals problem.

Comment: @Alex This isn't a code review :-) but thanks, that's a good suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason that the program is using `Long.equals`, even though all your test code uses `Matrix<Integer>`, is simply that you're storing a `Long` in it.  The code has this:

```
public class Matrix<T extends Number> {

    private T[] matrix = null;
```

and then in the constructor:

```
    this.matrix = (T[]) new Number[rows * cols];
```

which of course creates an array of `null` references.  But when you create the array using `multiply`,

```
Long result = 0l;
for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
     Long l = row[i].longValue() * column[i].longValue();
     result += l;
}
output.set(r, c, (T) result);
```

where `set` looks like

```
public void set(int row, int col, T value) {
    matrix[getIndex(row, col)] = value;
}
```

The thing is, that even though you tried to put a `(T)` cast on the result, it doesn't do anything.  Note that the language doesn't let you cast between `Long` and `Integer` types:

```
Long x = 3L;
Integer y = 4;
x = (Long)y;     // illegal
y = (Integer)x;  // illegal
```

Because of type erasure, the compiler doesn't try to check the cast to `(T)`, but displays an unchecked warning if you don't suppress warnings.  (It checks to make sure that the thing you're casting is some `Number`, but that's all.)  It does **not** generate any code that would do a conversion.  Thus, even if the multiply method is called on `Matrix<Integer>`, the code will not try to convert your `Long` to an `Integer`.  The cast has no effect, and the result is that a reference to a `Long` is stored in your `matrix` array.  (This runs OK because the code cannot check to make sure that the type is the same as `T`, again due to type erasure.)  So then later, when you use `matrix[i].equals`, since a `Long` is stored in the `matrix`, `Long.equals` is called.

Unfortunately, I don't think there's a good way to convert a number to an object of some `Number` class that isn't known at compile time.  You could pass `T`'s class as a parameter to the constructor, and then use reflection to try to find a constructor for that class that takes a `long` parameter, but that's ugly.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there is no way to check for value equality of Number implementations.

The closest thing you can generically do is:

```
public static boolean valueEquals(Number n1, Number n2) {
    return n1.longValue() == n2.longValue() && n1.doubleValue() == n2.doubleValue();
}
```

This method will return sane results for all primitive wrapper types, but not for all instances of BigDecimal, BigInteger and anything else that offers precision beyond the limits of long/double.
The reason both longValue and doubleValue are compared is that if you used only longValue, 1L and 1.1D would be detected as equal (due to truncation in Double.longValue()), while if you used just doubleValue, there would be multiple distinct long values that match a single double (e.g. integer values in the range of 2^53 to 2^63 can be exactly represented as longs, but they do get rounded in the least significant bits when represented as double).

Answer (score 1):

Since you already know that the values are not always instances of `Long`, you have to compare the numeric values yourself as you already found out.

To answer your question "I wonder [...] why the equals method on the generic T is assuming it's a Long":
Because it is one. When calling `t1.equals(t2)` with `t1` being a Long, the equality check is done by `Long.equals(Object)`. And that results in false if the parameter is not of the same type.

Since you cant be sure which type "arrives" in your equals method, you should implement a Comparator that can handle all the possible types. For instance: How do you compare an Integer to a Double? Both are subclasses of Number.

Comment: t1 and t2 are defined as Integer type in the testing code.

Answer (score -1):

> ...why the equals method on the generic T is assuming it's a Long.

The reason is simple: Assuming the matrix you're testing with is of type `Matrix<Long>`, then `t1` *is* an instance of `Long` (the generic type just allows you to use `Long` here and has no relevance at runtime) and thus `Long.equals()` would be called.

In the following case `Integer.equals()` should be called:

```
Matrix<Integer> m1 = ...;
Matrix<Long> m2 = ...;

m1.equals( m2 );
```

Since members of m1 are of type Integer, the call `t1.equals(t2)` would have the signature `Integer.equals(Long)`.

So what could you do to be able to get two matrices of different types but with equal values to be equal?

The general problem  would be that you should use `compareTo()` to check for value equality (since in some cases like `BigDecimal` mathematically equal values like 2.0 and 2.00 would not result in `equals()` returing true.

Unfortunately using `T extends Number & Comparable<T>` would not be an option (see the comments for reference, as well as here: [Why doesn't java.lang.Number implement Comparable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480632/why-doesnt-java-lang-number-implement-comparable)), because you would not be able to call `Long.compareTo(Integer)` that way.

Thus you'd either have to fall back to primitive values and distinguish between integer and floating point values (thus calling `t1.longValue()` *or* `t1.doubleValue()`) or use a `Comparator<Number>` whose implementation of `compareTo(Number lhs, Number rhs)` would handle that. (There should be ready to use `Comparators` like this: http://www.jidesoft.com/javadoc/com/jidesoft/comparator/NumberComparator.html).

If you want to support larger numbers like `BigInteger` and `BigDecimal` you could also consider using `BigDecimal` and create an instance for every value. This should result in some flexibility but would also incur some performance cost. (Disclaimer: this is just an untested idea so don't just take it as is, it is just meant to provide some input for your own thought process).

Comment: Thats ok, but why equals assume Long type?

Comment: @ArnaldoIgnacioGasparVéjar because in OP's example, the variable ``t1`` was a Long. Naturally, ``Long.equals(Object)`` is called.

Comment: @ArnaldoIgnacioGasparVéjar like f1sh said, `Long.equals()` is called and by definition of a Long only equals another Long with the same value (due to transitiveness).

Comment: Too bad that implementations of Number do not implement Comparable<Number>, in other words what you suggest doesn't even compile, much less works.

Comment: The OP does not mention that t1 is always Long

Comment: @Durandal, you're right, my bad. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Regarding your latest suggestion: have you tested it?  I'm dubious.  `Long.compareTo` requires another `Long` as a parameter (see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#compareTo(java.lang.Long))), and there won't be any automatic conversion of, say, `Integer` to `Long` since that happens only at compile time.  So I'm doubtful that this will work right.

Comment: @ajb You're right, Long.compareTo() requires a Long argument. In fact all primitive wrappers only have a compareTo() taking their own type. There is no Comparable<Number> among any of the primitives wrappers in the JDK.

Comment: @f1sh I've added the testing code which defines both Matrices as Matrix<Integer>

Comment: I tried a similar case using a generic with `<T extends Number & Comparable<T>>`.  I was able to create a program that compiled (with unchecked type warnings) that would attempt to call `Long.compareTo` with an `Integer`, but the result was `ClassCastException` at run time.  So `compareTo` is not a solution that would allow different `Number` types to be compared.